# Xamarin.Forms Change Background Color For Application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mobile

I want to change the background color for the whole application. I have been searching but I found nothing. Of course there's a way instead of changing the background color for each page right? Hope to get an answer soon. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There isn't one.  You can use styles to define an application wide background color, or use a common base class for all pages to do it

Comment: booooo for Microsoft. Thank your for your time. I want to ask one more question, how can I set the background color of a page using hexadecimal color? something like BackgroundColor = "#e9e7e7"

Comment: Color.FromHex()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look into [Xamarin.Forms Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/) where the Shell is the container of the entire application. This would enable you to have the background defined at only one area instead of every page. Furthermore, it would allow you to [customize it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/configuration) for specific pages if need be.

You can find their example application using a Shell called "Xanimals" [here](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/UserInterface/Xaminals).